# Python :getting the count for the adjectives in a string

Tags: python, counter, nltk

I have a string 
s= "Mr.X is awesome. He is amazing.Mr.Y is awesome too."

I need to extract all the adjectives from the string along with the count of each adjectives. For example 
This string has adjectives "awesome","amazing" with a count of 2 for awesome and 1 for amazing.

for extracting adjectives , I have used NLTK. This is the code for extracting adjectives,

```
adjectives =[token for token, pos in nltk.pos_tag(nltk.word_tokenize(b)) if pos.startswith('JJ')]
```

I need the code to get a counter for each adjective in the string.
It should be like
adjectives : counter

Comment: take a look at Counter in collections module.

Comment: The problem is that I have stored all the adjectives in a list. I dont think Counter works with list

Comment: see it on [pyMOTW](https://pymotw.com/2/collections/counter.html)

Comment: @DipitMalhotra It'll work with any sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`collections.Counter`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
>>> from collections import Counter

>>> adjectives = ['awesome', 'amazing', 'awesome']
>>> counts = Counter(adjectives)
>>> counts.items()
[('awesome', 2), ('amazing', 1)]
```

That can be converted into a dictionary if you like:

```
>>> dict(counts.items())
{'amazing': 1, 'awesome': 2}
```

Or you can access the keys and values:

```
>>> for key in counts.keys():
...     print key, counts.get(key)
awesome 2
amazing 1
```

edit:

For a list of lists, you need to [flatten the lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11264684/flatten-list-of-lists):

```
>>> adjectives = [['awesome', 'amazing'], ['good', 'nice' ]]
>>> counts = Counter(adjective
...                  for group in adjectives
...                  for adjective in group)
>>> counts
Counter({'awesome': 1, 'good': 1, 'amazing': 1, 'nice': 1})
```

Or using [**`itertools.chain.from_iterable`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> Counter(chain.from_iterable(adjectives))
Counter({'awesome': 1, 'good': 1, 'amazing': 1, 'nice': 1})
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution.. But I have another problem...My list adjectives haas multiple lists inside it . It is basically like adjectives= [['awesome,'amazing'], ['good', 'nice'  ]   So when I run the Counter..it gives an array: TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: @DipitMalhotra added list of lists solution

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution for your problem uses [Counter](https://pymotw.com/2/collections/counter.html). The full solution is this

```
s= "Mr.X is awesome He is amazing Mr.Y is awesome too."
adjectives=["awesome", "beautiful", "handsome", "amazing"]
c=collections.Counter(s.split())
for key in list(c):
    if (key not in adjectives):
        del c[key]
print c
```

I created a list with the adjectives, because I assume your solution already works for you.

Next I split the sentence using the spaces to create a list of tokens. Pay attention that this will not work correctly with punctuations (for example, your sentence has "awesome." and this will map to a different key than "awesome"), but you can split as well as you like.

The split is given to the Counter method, which creates a counter object, which is a dict.

Then I iterate over key and remove all those keys that are not included in my list of adjectives. Notice that my `for` iterates over `list(c)` because `del` will cause the Counter to change size and if I used it straight, we would get an error in the `for` (object changed size).

I hope it helps. I believe you can fit it into your code.