# Converting 2D String array into 1D String array in Python

Tags: python, arrays

I have a string array that looks like this:

```
string = [ [ "this is a sample",
             "this is another sample"],
           [ "The third sample",
             "the fourth one"] ]
```

But I want to convert it to:

```
string = [   "this is a sample",
             "this is another sample",
             "The third sample",
             "the fourth one"  ]
```

How can I do it?
I know I can do it by pre-allocating a string and iterating. But is there a simpler method?

Comment: Google "Python flatten list of lists". Also refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11264684/flatten-list-of-lists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this using list comprehension. 
Code:

```
string = [ [ "this is a sample",
         "this is another sample"],
       [ "The third sample",
         "the fourth one"] ]

print([_ for i in range(len(string)) for _ in string[i]])
```

Comment: I did not know two for loops like this could be written. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: It's called nested for loop. http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/python-single-line-loops

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use list comprehension. Something like

```
string = [s for S in string for s in S]
```