# Create duplicates in the list

Tags: python, list

I have

```
 list = [a, b, c, d]
```

and

```
numbers = [2, 4, 3, 1]
```

I want to get a list of the type of:

```
new_list = [a, a, b, b, b, b, c, c, c, d]
```

This is what I have so far:

```
new_list=[] 
for i in numbers: 
    for x in list: 
        for i in range(1,i+1): 
            new_list.append(x)
```

Comment: @Ekaterina edit your question to include that piece of code, not in the comments.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's one way to do it using `zip`, string multiplication and a *list comprehension*:

```
lst = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'] 
numbers = [2 , 4, 3, 1]

r = [x for i, j in zip(lst, numbers) for x in i*j]
print(r)
# ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'd']
```

Pay attention to the choice of names when using Python. A name like `list` renders the builtin list function unusable.

If the items in `lst` are not strings you can simply use a nested comprehension on `range`, to duplicate the items in the list.

Comment: OP didn't specify that `a`, `b`, etc are strings.  Your solution only works based on the assumption that "`list`" contains a bunch of sequences.

Answer (score 5):

A nested list comprehension works:

```
L = ['a','b','c','d']
numbers = [2, 4, 3, 1]

>>> [x for x, number in zip(L, numbers) for _ in range(number)]
['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'd']
```

The "sub-loop" `for _ in range(number)` repeats the value `number` times.
Here `L` can hold any object, not only strings.

Example:

```
L = [[1, 2, 3],'b','c', 'd']
numbers = [2, 4, 3, 1]
[x for x, number in zip(L, numbers) for _ in range(number)]
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'd']
```

but this flattens the sub list:

```
[x for i, j in zip(L, numbers) for x in i*j]
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'd']
```

not exactly the desired result.

Answer (score 5):

As a general approach for any object (not only string) you can use  `itertools.repeat()` within a generator expression:

```
def repeat_it(lst, numbers):
    return chain.from_iterable(repeat(i, j) for i, j in zip(lst, numbers))
```

Demo:

```
In [13]: from itertools import repeat, chain

In [21]: lst=[5,4,6,0]

In [22]: list(repeat_it(lst, numbers))
Out[22]: [5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 6, 6, 6, 0]

In [23]: lst=['a','b','c','d']

In [24]: list(repeat_it(lst, numbers))
Out[24]: ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'd']
```

Here is a benchmark on 3 main approaches. Note that the last one onley works for strings:

```
In [49]: lst = lst * 1000

In [50]: numbers = numbers * 1000

In [51]: %timeit list(chain.from_iterable(repeat(i, j) for i, j in zip(lst, numbers)))
1 loops, best of 3: 8.8 s per loop

In [52]: %timeit [x for x, number in zip(lst, numbers) for _ in range(number)]
1 loops, best of 3: 12.4 s per loop

In [53]: %timeit [x for i, j in zip(lst, numbers) for x in i*j]
1 loops, best of 3: 7.2 s per loop
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `numpy.repeat()` as another option:

```
import numpy as np
np.repeat(lst, numbers).tolist()

# ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'd']
```

Comment: Note that this requires you to install numpy, which is overkill if you are just solving this one problem

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it with a loop would be:

```
new_list = []
for number, item in zip(numbers, l):
    for i in range(number):
        new_list.append(item)
```

Now we have:

```
new_list = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'd']
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are unsure of how list comprehensions work,

```
myList=['a','b','c','d'] # not a good idea to use list as a name for your variable
numbers=[2,4,3,1]
new_list=[]
for i in range(len(myList)):     
    for j in range(numbers[i]):          
        new_list.append(myList[i])

print(new_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work regardless of whether a, b, c and d are variables or strings:

```
a = 1
b = 2.0
c = "cheese"
d = ["c", "a", "k", "e"]

lst = [a, b, c, d]
numbers = [2, 4, 3, 1]

# if len(lst) == len(numbers):
new_lst = [i for i, j in zip(lst, numbers) for k in range(j)]
```

You might want to uncomment the if statement (and indent the line underneath) to check if the lists have the same length, otherwise new_lst will only contain as many items as the shorter list.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406121/flattening-a-shallow-list-in-python), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11264684/flatten-list-of-lists) and [the documentation section on nested list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#nested-list-comprehensions) are worth reading.

Answer (score 1):

That's my solution, just to add a different one.

```
l = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
n = [2, 4, 3, 1]
r = []
for i,v in enumerate(l):
    r += list(v*n[i])

>>> r
    ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'd']
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that both lists are the same length and the second is always a list of numbers, here is a solution without using `zip` or any imports:

```
lst = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
numbers = [2,4,3,1]

result = sum([[lst[i]]*numbers[i] for i in range(len(lst))],[])
```

Comment: This is a *shlemiel the painter* algorithm, and one of the worst ways that you can go for solving this problem.

Comment: @Kasramvd How so?

Comment: @Kasramvd, yes thanks, i've read it, i'm asking how it applies here