# Python How remove sublist duplicate side by side?

Tags: python, python-2.7

My question is: I have this list:

```
[['x', '2', 'NOT'], [['sw'], ['y', '1', 'P12'], ['sw']], [['sw'],
['y', '2', 'NOT'], ['sw']], ['x', 'P01'], ['y', 'Xt']]
```

I'd like to delete the elements duplicate when they appear side by side.
Example:['sw']], [['sw']

The end result should be:

```
 [['x', '2', 'NOT'], ['sw'], ['y', '1', 'P12'], ['y', '2', 'NOT'], ['sw'], 
 ['x', 'P01'], ['y', 'Xt']]
```

I have tried a lot, but I can do that.

Comment: The first step is to make the nesting of your lists uniform. The answers to [this recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45502776/partial-list-flattening-in-python) show how to do that. And then you can search for adjacent duplicates. One way to do that is to use [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)

Comment: What you type is wrong. This two elements ['sw']] [['sw'] belong two DIFFERENT nested lists so they are not side by side. You have a big list that has nested lists as elements. What exactly do you want to achieve? To create a big list with unique elements?

Comment: @MichailN my interpreter isn't complaining...

Comment: You should post your own code attempt, even though it doesn't give the desired result. Questions like this without some code often attract downvotes.

Comment: @ juanpa.arrivillaga I mean logically wrong not syntactically

Comment: @PM2Ring thank you!!!

Comment: @MichailN I think it's fairly obvious what Caroline wants to achieve, since she has posted the expected output for that sample input. Clearly, the output should be a list of lists, with any runs of identical sublists deleted.

Comment: @MichailN   It is not exactly creating a large list with unique elements, it would be to create a list deleting equal and adjacent elements.

Comment: @MichailN has a valid point, the adjacent elements ['sw'], ['y', '1', 'P12'], ['sw'] and ['sw'], ['y', '2', 'NOT'], ['sw'], are not equal. The two ['sw'] in the original list are part of a nested element

Comment: @SimonBlack  I made a single list, now I have [['x', '2', 'NOT'], ['sw'], ['y', '1', 'P12'], ['sw'], ['sw'], ['y', '2', 'NOT'], ['sw'], ['x', 'P01'], ['y', 'Xt']]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove the duplicate elements,

```
mylist=[['x', '2', 'NOT'], ['sw'], ['y', '1', 'P12'], ['sw'], ['sw'], ['y', '2', 'NOT'], ['sw'], ['x', 'P01'], ['y', 'Xt']]
print (mylist)

newlist=[]
for i, e in enumerate(mylist):
    try:
        if not (mylist[i-1] == mylist[i] or mylist[i] == mylist[i+1]):
            newlist.append(e)
    except IndexError:
        newlist.append(e)

print (newlist)
```

Gives the results

```
[['x', '2', 'NOT'], ['sw'], ['y', '1', 'P12'], ['sw'], ['sw'], ['y', '2', 'NOT'], ['sw'], ['x', 'P01'], ['y', 'Xt']]
[['x', '2', 'NOT'], ['sw'], ['y', '1', 'P12'], ['y', '2', 'NOT'], ['sw'], ['x', 'P01']]
```

Comment: Simon it's working !!! thank you very much!!! I had this problem for days.

Comment: Simon , Why does not the last element print? I'm still new to programming, I'm a little lost.

Comment: I've updated the code (It was the exception handling) this will be thrown on the very last element so needs to add this element to the list rather than to just continue

Answer (score 0):

Can do this with list comprehension and enumerate (to get the index)

```
mylist=[['x', '2', 'NOT'], ['sw'], ['y', '1', 'P12'], ['sw'], ['sw'], ['y', '2', 'NOT'], ['sw'], ['x', 'P01'], ['y', 'Xt']]
print (mylist)

newlist=[e for i, e in enumerate(mylist) if mylist[i-1] != mylist[i]]
print (newlist)
```

Here's the output

```
[['x', '2', 'NOT'], ['sw'], ['y', '1', 'P12'], ['sw'], ['sw'], ['y', '2', 'NOT'], ['sw'], ['x', 'P01'], ['y', 'Xt']]
[['x', '2', 'NOT'], ['sw'], ['y', '1', 'P12'], ['sw'], ['y', '2', 'NOT'], ['sw'], ['x', 'P01'], ['y', 'Xt']]
```

Comment: The problem is that when I have duplicate elements I need to remove both. And obtain the following:
     [['x', '2', 'NOT'], ['sw'], ['y', '1', 'P12'], ['y', '2', 'NOT'], ['sw'], ['x', 'P01'], ['y', 
      'Xt']]