# Flatten a lists of list with some lists have multiple values - python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I was going through this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11264684/flatten-list-of-lists), which has some great answers, but it does not work for my situation.

I have a list like this:

```
my_list = [['Hi'],['Hello'],['How', 'are'], ['you']]
```

I did the flattening and I am getting this,

```
my_flat_list = [i[0] for i in my_list]
my_flat_list
>>['Hi', 'Hello', 'How', 'you']
```

If I don't use `i[0]` I get in list format again.

The output I need is:

```
['Hi', 'Hello', 'How are', 'you']
```

I also tired this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406121/flattening-a-shallow-list-in-python) using `itertools` still not getting my desired results.

How can I get my output?

Comment: Looks like you want `[' '.join(i) for i in my_list]`

Comment: @Poshi, Nope, not a dupe of that.

Comment: @DyZ  Question, how did you search that SO post? I have been Googling, did not find any related to my situation, then I posted this question. Is there a trick? May be always use a keyword involved? or anything else?

Comment: @user9431057 I found that dupe by googling "How to join sublists of strings in python".  While yes, this ends up flattening the list, most list flattening questions don't join elements of the sublists, which is why you wouldn't have been able to find it.

Comment: @user3483203 Okay, in the beginning I had no idea that it needs a join. I have been googling 'how to flatten lists' :(. Thank for the comment, love to learn with you all :)

Comment: Happy to help.  You asked a good question with all the necessary information, so keep it up!

Comment: There are two steps to the problem, and each is a common duplicate. `' '.join` can join a list of strings; apply that to each list in the list of lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[str.join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) will help you turn every sublist to a single string:

```
In [1]: [' '.join(sublist) for sublist in my_list]
Out[1]: ['Hi', 'Hello', 'How are', 'you']
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to join the inner lists:

```
list(map(" ".join, my_list))
#['Hi', 'Hello', 'How are', 'you']
```

Comment: `join` helps a lot. Awesome!