# How to get arrays that ouput result in brackets like [1][2][3] to [1 2 3]

Tags: python, arrays

The title kind of says it all. I have this (excerpt):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

number_of_particles=1000

phi = np.arccos(1-2*np.random.uniform(0.0,1.,(number_of_particles,1)))
vc=2*pi
mux=-vc*np.sin(phi)
```

and I get out

```
[[-4.91272413]
 [-5.30620302]
 [-5.22400513]
 [-5.5243784 ]
 [-5.65050497]...]
```

which is correct, but I want it to be in the format

```
[-4.91272413 -5.30620302 -5.22400513 -5.5243784 -5.65050497....]
```

Feel like there should be a simple solution, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: It seems like you want to flatten a list of lists.

Comment: @ouroborus Oh yes, I think you're right. I found something similar here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11264684/flatten-list-of-lists/11264799

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make a flat list out of a list of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-do-i-make-a-flat-list-out-of-a-list-of-lists)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your array is represented by the variable arr.
You can do,

```
l = ''
for i in arr:
   l = l+i+' '
arr = [l]
```

Comment: change my statement from l = l+i+'  ' to l=l+str(i[0])+'  '

Answer (score 0):

Use this command:

```
 new_mux = [i[0] for i in mux]
```

But I need it in an array, so then I add this

```
new_mux=np.array(new_mux)
```

and I get the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

There's a method `transpose` in numpy's array object

```
 mux.transpose()[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

(I just noticed that this is a very old question, but since I have typed up this answer, and I believe it is simpler and more efficient than the existing ones, I'll post it...)

Notice that when you do

```
np.random.uniform(0.0,1.,(number_of_particles, 1))
```

you are creating a two-dimensional array with number_of_particles rows and one column. If you want a one-dimensional array throughout, you could do

```
np.random.uniform(0.0,1.,(number_of_particles,))
```

instead.

If you want to keep things 2d, but reshape `mux` for some reason, you can... well, `reshape` it:

```
mux_1d = mux.reshape(-1)
```

`-1` here means "reshape it to one axis (because there’s just one number) and figure out automatically home many elements there should be along that axis (because the number is -1)."