# Set operation in 2D array in Python

Tags: python, list, set

Is it possible to use set operation for a 2D array in python. For example,

```
>>> a = [['a', 's'], 
         ['a', 'b'], 
         ['a', 's']]
>>> print(set(a))
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                               
File "main.py", line 5, in <module>                                                                                                            
print(set(a))                                                                                                                                
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

It shows this error. I need a output of `{'a', 's'}, {'a', 'b'}`. So is it possible to get this output in any other method.

Comment: If you want the unique elements, not the unique arrays, then try creating the set of *flattened* input [using itertools.chain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11264684/flatten-list-of-lists/11264799)

Comment: My input is list of lists. So I need to do  set operation for that list of lists.

Comment: But your own expected output is the set of *elements* `{'a', 's'}`, not the set of lists `{['a','s']}`. If you really want the lists, you need to convert them into something [hashable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14535730/what-does-hashable-mean-in-python) -- such as a tuple, `set(tuple(t) for t in a)` -- aha you have changed the question as I'm typing this!

Comment: I have updated my question. I think it explain it clearly now

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion Mr.@mrblewog

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apply function to each element of a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25082410/apply-function-to-each-element-of-a-list) Simply apply `set` to each element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flatten it first:

```
a = [['a', 's'], 
     ['a', 's'], 
     ['a', 's']]
print(set(y for x in a for y in x))  # {'a', 's'}
```

EDIT: From the updated question, convert it to tuple first then convert the final output to set. Note that sets are not always arranged like the original values.

```
a = [['a', 's'], 
    ['a', 'b'], 
    ['a', 's']]
print([set(y) for y in set(tuple(x) for x in a)])  # [{'a', 's'}, {'a', 'b'}]
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I have updated my question so that you can understand it clearly.

Answer (score 0):

You are apparently after the distinct *lists*, per your clarification comment.

`list` objects aren't hashable in Python because, essentially, they are mutable and their hash codes can be changed by changing their data. So you want/need to make a `set` of hashable objects.

```py
a = [['a', 's'], 
...          ['a', 'b'], 
...          ['a', 's']]

>>> set(tuple(t) for t in a)  # << unique tuples made of arrays in 'a'
{('a', 's'), ('a', 'b')}

>>> [list(x) for x in set(tuple(t) for t in a)] # << list of lists, will be unique by set(...)
[['a', 's'], ['a', 'b']]

>>> [set(x) for x in set(tuple(t) for t in a)] # << further, unique elements of the unique lists in a
[{'s', 'a'}, {'b', 'a'}]
```

But you can't make a true `set` of `lists` because of the hashing problem.