# How can I remove the square brackets in Python?

Tags: python

For example, I have a list of lists:

```
[[['--w'], ['ww-'], ['bbb']], [['w--'], ['-ww'], ['bbb']]]
```

I want to remove inner one to be like this

```
[['--w', 'ww-', 'bbb'], ['w--', '-ww', 'bbb']]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What have you tried yourself? What happened? What did you expect?

Comment: is this a list with a single element who is a list of lists? you might be able to return the first index

Comment: Don't change your questions after they've been asked to invalidate existing answers. Your post-change question is just an extension of [Flatten list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11264684/364696); you'd apply the answers to that question inside a `list` comp over the outermost `list` to flatten the inner `list`s.

Answer (score 3):

If this is just for the purposes of printing, you can do:

```
list_o_lists_o_lists = [[['--w'], ['ww-'], ['bbb']], [['w--'], ['-ww'], ['bbb']]]
print(*list_o_lists_o_lists, sep=", ")
```

which unpacks the outer `list` into its two inner `list`s as sequential arguments to `print`, which prints each separately, while `sep=", "` tells `print` to place a comma and space between each of them, getting the display you want, but making no change to the data structure.

But otherwise, what you want isn't possible as stated; removing the outer brackets leaves you with two elements that need to be stored in *something*. The literal with those brackets removed is a `tuple`:

```
[['--w'], ['ww-'], ['bbb']], [['w--'], ['-ww'], ['bbb']]
```

but the `repr` of a `tuple` includes parentheses, so you'd just be replacing the outer brackets with parens if you printed it without special formatting effort:

```
>>> [['--w'], ['ww-'], ['bbb']], [['w--'], ['-ww'], ['bbb']]
([['--w'], ['ww-'], ['bbb']], [['w--'], ['-ww'], ['bbb']])
```

Comment: this variable naming... it hurts my eyes

Comment: @megargayu: Yeah, it's awful. :-) But it also makes it clear for the example what the structure is. The OP talks about removing brackets, but they're not decorative, they're the outer `list`, and they have to know that.

Comment: For that purpose, it would be much easier (and cleaner) to use a comment

Comment: For throwaway examples? Who cares? I'm definitely not suggesting they actually use this name in real code, but I haven't the foggiest notion what this data is supposed to represent, so that's about as descriptive as I can be.

Comment: Okay, I guess you are correct. Just for whoever reads this: DO NOT NAME YOUR VARIABLES "`list_o_lists_o_lists`"!!! Instead, use short variable names that make sense and add comments for an extra description.

Answer (score 0):

Your description doesn't match your desired output. Your desired output has the inner brackets removed, not the outer ones. To remove the inner brackets, you can do

```
[[item[0] for item in inner_list] for inner_list in outer_list]
```

Comment: which one is item and which one is inner_list?

Comment: Sigh... They edited the question to completely change the desired output format, while leaving the description of their goal unchanged.

Comment: @myy39 `item` and `inner_list` are both dummy variables. They exist while iterating through a list, but don't refer to anything outside. `outer_list` refers to the entire list, and it's the only variable that has to be defined.

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
[[j[0] for j in i] for i in [[['--w'], ['ww-'], ['bbb']], [['w--'], ['-ww'], ['bbb']]]]
```

Output:

```
[['--w', 'ww-', 'bbb'], ['w--', '-ww', 'bbb']]
```

Comment: origin[0] will give [['--w'], ['ww-'], ['bbb']]

Comment: Can someexplain to me why people think this works and why they upvoted?

Comment: @toptalent: You could just as easily write `result1, result2 = origin` in this case, no need to build a new `tuple` just to unpack it. But it still doesn't have an *output*, you're saying you'll see it in a specific way without actually showing how you display it (now that you're unpacking, there are multiple "its" involved, so "output" makes even less sense).

Comment: this is some complex list comprehension... maybe split it up into different variables so its actually readable? Also, a description of what is even happening here would be nice.